# Remote storage software for my web development projects

Tags: web-development, file-synchronization

Due to the nature of my studies and work I usually work on two different computers to do my web development: my desktop at home and my laptop anywhere else. Right now I keep my website projects in my Apache local server on my Linux machine.

**I would like to find software to solve the problem of having to copy and paste files from my desktop computer to my laptop and vice versa whenever changes have been made.** What is the best option, and what software works best for the purpose?

- Paying a SSH-able server and keeping my projects there.
- Using Git (not really the best since only I work on these projects).
- Using cloud storage like Dropbox?
- What else? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I always use DropBox for the main branch, but I also use version control (on one machine only) and so should you. A one man project is no excuse - don't you want to be able to revert to saved (stable) versions, make comparisons, etc? GitHub would be fine. As a free alternative to DropBox which doesn't use other people's servers, look into BitTorrent Synch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options that would work:

1. Git may be a good option even if (currently) it is only you working in the project (personally, I would go with this one)
2. SVN (but, why? git is better even if you don't use the distributed part)
3. Dropbox (or the like). If you are always (or frequently) connected, is a good option. Beware of name clashes if you use a case-sensitive file-system (e.g. Linux) and a case-insensitive one (i.e. Windows). Also, make sure to define your compiled/minified/whatever files to go outside the synced directory (otherwise you will be uploading/downloading unnecessary data)

Comment: Your answer led me to research more on Github, and I found https://bitbucket.org which allows free storage of private repos, I'm convinced now :)

Comment: @FaustoNA Note that if you'd have one of your machines accessible from "the outer world", Git also can be setup as server – so you wouldn't need any 3rd party service at all.

Comment: I see, that sounds great too... I really like the idea of a Raspberry Pi running eternally in my room...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need source control repository server and can use GitHub or BitBucket.

I just want to add [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) to this list. It's free for small team (<5).

You can use it not only for Visual Studio, but for any IDE.

And you can use Git or TFVC for version control, depending what you prefer.